# Root privilege using Return-to-libc attack

Tags: vulnerability

I've been working on [Return-to-libc Attack Lab from SEED](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Software/Return_to_libc/) ([Lab Description and Tasks](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Software/Return_to_libc/Return_to_libc.pdf)). The environment is Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. Please consider the following code:

```
/* This program has a buffer overflow vulnerability. */
/* Our task is to exploit this vulnerability */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int bof(FILE *badfile)
{
    char buffer[12];

    /* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 40, badfile);

    return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *badfile;

    badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
    bof(badfile);

    printf("Returned Properly\n");

    fclose(badfile);
    return 1;
}
```

I found the desired addresses, designed badfile so that it changes the content of the stack as in the sketch below and checked it with the debugger ([source](https://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2017/readings/return-to-libc.pdf)):

```
[-] Buffer overflow doing return-to-libc and executing system function
                                                  1             2        3
|---------------------------|------------|--------------|------------|
|           buffer          |   system   |   fake_ret   |  /bin/sh   |
|---------------------------|------------|--------------|------------|
               args              EBP           EIP
```

I was able to open the shell but for some reason I did not get the privilege of the root:

```
[02/14/2018 16:22] seed@ubuntu:~/Documents$ gdb -q retlib
Reading symbols from /home/seed/Documents/retlib...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/seed/Documents/retlib 
$ whoami
seed
$ id
uid=1000(seed) gid=1000(seed) groups=1000(seed),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare),130(wireshark)
$
```

I checked the vulnerable program and it was properly compiled (according to the lab's instructions), the program is Set-UID:

```
[02/14/2018 16:35] seed@ubuntu:~/Documents$ ls -l retlib
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 9712 Feb 11 06:41 retlib
```

Can someone please explain why I did not get the privilege of the root after I opened the shell?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of searching, I found out that environment variables have a different address when running the program under GDB.
So, the solution to my problem was simply to write a short program in C that prints the address of the environment variable I was looking for. Then, the solution was obvious to me.

Comment: If you run a suid program from gdb, you will not get the suid privileges.